# Run two keywords in Robot Framewok in parallel

Tags: appium, robotframework

I use robot framework with Appium library to automate an application.
I want to test there a graph functionality. When user long presses somewhere on the graph and holds his/her finger the values are shown for that date, as soon as user stops pressing the values disappear.
I tried to `Long Press` the graph and check that `page should contain text` or `wait until page contains` passing the expected text to appear, but the case always fails, as at the time when robot framework starts to check the text it is already disappeared.

So as I understand what I really need is to make two keywords run in parallel. The following two ones:

`Long Press  5000`

`wait until page contains  someText`

I googled and seems that some time ago there was a way to run parallel keywords, but now they removed it from framework. 
So does anyone know how can I test this case or is it possible at all?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/awadhn/robotframework-run-keyword-async/blob/master/runKeywordAsync/runKeywordAsync.py?

Comment: @WojtekT thanks for lib! It actually works async, but it does not do what I want in a mysterious way. It really does the long press async, and the text that I expect to be on screen appears, but the than my testcase fails telling that text does not apear in 5 seconds. when I press on screen manually everything works as expected.

Comment: If the text appears then i would say you have some kind of error in your keyword  check your locator make sure it all matches any typos etc.